# Form elements overwrite default properties of a form object

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Let's say we have a form with the following inputs: (and yes, what if we really want to have those names)

```
<form id="form-id">
    <input type="text" name="submit" />
    <input type="text" name="elements" />
    <input type="text" name="id" />
    <input type="text" name="addEventListener" />
</form>
```

Now, if we try to access form properties, all we get is input objects:

```
var form = document.getElementById('form-id');

form.elements; // will be <input type="text" name="elements" /> instead of a list of elements
```

same problem with:

```
form.submit;
form.id;
form.addEventListener;
```

and all other default properties of a form object.

I do understand that we could find some other way to access those properties...
but what should we do with those that we can't?

Your suggestions.

Comment: What properties can't you find another way to access?

Comment: Avoid using keywords as names. If you must, then you must go through the tedious property of managing a broken state. Remove the name from the element, save the location of `.submit` or `.elements`, and then reassign the name.

Comment: @Alohci how do I get the form.elements array in a constant time having an input named "elements" ?

Comment: Browsers work the way they do and your Stackoverflow question, no matter how well-intentioned, is not going to change that.

Comment: Is there a question here? Or are you just asking us for our opinion on your opinion that standards should be different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course the easiest way is to thumb-down the question and forget about it. But I went further and found out how to solve this problem. So I'll just leave it here. IE9+

```
HTMLFormElement.prototype.getRealAttribute = function(name) {
    var form = this;
    var tmpForm = document.createElement('FORM');

    /* if it's not overridden */
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(tmpForm[name]) === Object.prototype.toString.call(form[name])) {
        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(tmpForm[name]) === "[object Function]") {
            return form[name].bind(form);
        }
        return form[name];
    }

    /* if it's overridden function */
    if (HTMLFormElement.prototype[name]) {
        return HTMLFormElement.prototype[name].bind(form);
    }

    /* if it's an attribute */
    if (form.attributes[name]) {
        return form.attributes[name].value;
    }

    /* if it's an overridden property */
    var fieldSet = document.createElement('FIELDSET');
    fieldSet.innerHTML = form.innerHTML;

    return fieldSet[name] || null;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for answering the question that looks legit to me, although the fact that the standard is wrong is irrelevant (but true... but irrelevant). However, note that this would still fail for an input named `getRealAttribute`, `attributes` or `innerHTML`.

Comment: @AntoinePinsard you're killing me :D